# Python, subclassing immutable types

Tags: python, set, immutability

I've the following class:

```
class MySet(set):

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        if isinstance(arg, basestring):
            arg = arg.split()
        set.__init__(self, arg)
```

This works as expected (initialising the set with the words of the string rather than the letters).  However when I want to do the same with the immutable version of set, the `__init__` method seems to be ignored:

```
class MySet(frozenset):

    def __init__(self, arg=None):
        if isinstance(arg, basestring):
            arg = arg.split()
        frozenset.__init__(self, arg)
```

Can I achieve something similar with `__new__` ?

Comment: I think the reason that `__new__(..)` takes the initiative when it comes to sculpting instances of immutable types is to take advantage of the immutability and reserve an opportunity to return an existing instance if available. (But if one doesn't want that advantage, then they could make an immutable type without messing with `__new__(..)`. In particular, `__new__(..)` doesn't offer any special context. One would still have to modify immutable fields via `object.__setattr__(..)` or similar, whether that's within `__new__(..)` or `__init_(..)`.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you need to override `__new__` special method:

```
class MySet(frozenset):

    def __new__(cls, *args):
        if args and isinstance (args[0], basestring):
            args = (args[0].split (),) + args[1:]
        return super (MySet, cls).__new__(cls, *args)

print MySet ('foo bar baz')
```

And the output is:

```
MySet(['baz', 'foo', 'bar'])
```

Comment: super! 
can __init__ be deprecated?

Comment: @EoghanM: No, `__new__` is different.  Basically, `__new__` creates *or* lookups an instance, while `__init__` setups an already created instance.  Main reasons to override `__new__` is to avoid new instance creation (e.g. to make `SomeType ()` always return the same singleton object), or to subclass certain immutable types, like `frozenset`.  See http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names for details.

Comment: thx - my sub question posed more clearly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131488/

Comment: See also [the FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-can-a-subclass-control-what-data-is-stored-in-an-immutable-instance) in the Python documentation.