# Python ignores default values of arguments supplied to tuple in inherited class

Tags: python, inheritance, constructor, tuples

Here is some code to demonstrate what I'm talking about.

```
class Foo(tuple):
   def __init__(self, initialValue=(0,0)):
      super(tuple, self).__init__(initialValue)

print Foo()
print Foo((0, 0))
```

I would expect both expressions to yield the exact same result, but the output of this program is:

```
()
(0, 0)
```

What am I not understanding here?

Comment: I believe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120562/python-subclassing-immutable-types) might be illuminating.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's because the `tuple` type does not care about the arguments to `__init__`, but only about those to `__new__`. This will make it work:

```
class Bar(tuple):
    @staticmethod
    def __new__(cls, initialValue=(0,0)):
        return tuple.__new__(cls, initialValue)
```

The basic reason for this is that, since tuples are immutable, they need to be pre-constructed with their data before you can even see them at the Python level. If the data were supplied via `__init__`, you would basically have an empty tuple at the start of your own `__init__` which then changed when you called `super().__init__()`.

Comment: [Here's another detailed explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1565448/1460057).

Comment: does it happen with arrays as well ?

Comment: @levi: Not if you, by "array", mean `list`s. They take their arguments through `__init__`.

Comment: `__new__` is static even without explicit declaration of that