# Subclassing `frozenset` with multiple `__init__` parameters, and strange behaviour of `__new__`

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance, constructor

Before you mark this a duplicate, I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565374/subclassing-python-tuple-with-multiple-init-arguments) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120562/python-subclassing-immutable-types?noredirect=1) and they don't answer my question (and even seem to confuse me more, not to mention that they're both in Python 2 and I want to know about Python 3). From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565374/subclassing-python-tuple-with-multiple-init-arguments), understand why the following code,

```
from typing import Hashable


class UnorderedPair(frozenset):
    def __init__(self, left: Hashable, right: Hashable):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        super().__init__((left, right))
        if len(self) != 2:
            raise TypeError("There must be 2 distinct elements. Possible duplicate in {{{}, {}}}.".format(left, right))

    def __str__(self):
        return "{{left: {}, right: {}}}".format(self.left, self.right)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = UnorderedPair(1, 2)
    print(p)
```

produces the following error.

```
TypeError: UnorderedPair expected at most 1 arguments, got 2
```

It's because I need to override `__new__()` as well as `__init__()`. However, this is where it gets confusing for me. Following the answers to [the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565374/subclassing-python-tuple-with-multiple-init-arguments), it looks like I should override `__new__()` as follows.

```
from typing import Hashable


class UnorderedPair(frozenset):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    def __init__(self, left: Hashable, right: Hashable):
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        super().__init__((left, right))
        if len(self) != 2:
            raise TypeError("There must be 2 distinct elements. Possible duplicate in {{{}, {}}}.".format(left, right))

    def __str__(self):
        return "{{left: {}, right: {}}}".format(self.left, self.right)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = UnorderedPair(1, 2)
    print(p)
```

But this gives me the same error. So maybe I should override it as follows (some code omitted because it's the same as before).

```
def __new__(cls, left: Hashable, right: Hashable):
    return super().__new__(cls, (left, right))
```

But this gives the following very cryptic error.

```
    super().__init__((left, right))
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

What does it have to do with `object.__init__()`!?!?!? Anyway, perhaps then I should override like the following.

```
def __new__(cls, left: Hashable, right: Hashable):
    return super().__new__(cls)
```

But this still gives the same error.

```
    super().__init__((left, right))
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters
```

So, how do I do this properly and make it work? (I think my intentions are clear from the non-working definition of the class.)

Comment: `frozenset` apparently does not define an `__init__()` (immutable objects generally don't), so your `super` call is being passed all the way up to the root `object` class - which takes no parameters.  Either avoid calling `super().__init__()`, or get rid of your `__init__` and do everything in `__new__`.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper. Some questions:

1. How do you know that `frozenset` doesn't define `__init__()`? How would I find out things like this myself? (Teach a man to fish.)

2. Why do immutable types use `__new__()` to allow subclasses? What can it do that `__init__()` can't???

Comment: A truly immutable type HAS to use `__new__()`, because there's no mechanism for setting the initial value at any later time - if `__init__()` was capable of setting the value, anybody could reset the value later, thus violating the immutability.  `__new__()` also gives the possibility of returning an existing, cached value instead of creating a new one.