# Can pandas.DatetimeIndex remember whether it is closed?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a `pandas.DatetimeIndex` for an interval `['2018-01-01', '2018-01-04')` (start included, end excluded) and `freq=1D`:

```
>>> index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2018-01-01',
                             end='2018-01-04',
                             freq='1D',
                             closed='left')
DatetimeIndex(['2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]',
              freq='D')
```

How can I obtain the correct open `end='2018-01-04'` attribute again? I need it for a DB query with timestamp ranges.

1. There is no `index.end`
2. `index[-1]` returns `'2018-01-03'`
3. `index[-1] + index.freq` works in this case but is wrong for `freq='2D'`

Comment: Why do not use `max(index)` ?

Comment: because it would return `index[-1]` and not the end parameter.

Comment: @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia `max(index)` returns `'2018-01-03'` just like `index[-1]`. I want `'2018-01-04'` because this is what was my `end` in the constructor.

Comment: Why not just save it when you create the index?

Comment: @user3483203 I could create a dummy object with `start/end/freq` attributes and then pass it around and create the `DatetimeIndex` on the fly only when I need it. Not so practical if this `DatetimeIndex` is already attached to an existing `DataFrame`. I'd like to avoid keeping too many variables around.

Comment: I think you're going to have to store it yourself: I can't see it stored inside the index, and since different `end` values can generate the same index values, you can't recover it after the fact in general.

Comment: why `index[-1] + index.freq` wrong?

Comment: @PankajJoshi because for `freq=2D` the `index[-1]` would be `2018-01-04` and adding `index.freq` would return `2018-01-06` which is not the original `end`.

Comment: @eumiro ah, right. Seems info is simply lost

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way because this information is lost after constructing the object. At creation time, the interval is unfolded into the resulting sequence:

`pandas/core/indexes/datetimes.py`:

```
class DatetimeIndex(<...>):

    <...>

    @classmethod
    def _generate(cls, start, end, periods, name, freq,
                  tz=None, normalize=False, ambiguous='raise', closed=None):
        <...>

                index = tools.to_datetime(np.linspace(start.value,
                                                      end.value, periods),
                                          utc=True)
                <...>

        if not left_closed and len(index) and index[0] == start:
            index = index[1:]
        if not right_closed and len(index) and index[-1] == end:
            index = index[:-1]
        index = cls._simple_new(index, name=name, freq=freq, tz=tz)
        return index
```

Neither is `closed` information saved anywhere, so you can't even infer it from the first/last point and step.

---

You can subclass `DatetimeIndex` and save this information. Note that [it's an immutable type, so you need to override `__new__` instead of `__init__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3120562/python-subclassing-immutable-types):

```
import inspect, collections
class SiDatetimeIndex(pd.DatetimeIndex):

    _Interval = collections.namedtuple('Interval',
            ('start','end','freq','closed'))
    #add 'interval' to dir(): DatetimeIndex inherits pandas.core.accessor.DirNamesMixin
    _accessors = pd.DatetimeIndex._accessors | frozenset(('interval',))

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        base_new = super(SiDatetimeIndex,cls).__new__
        callargs = inspect.getcallargs(base_new,cls,*args,**kwargs)
        result = base_new(**callargs)
        result.interval = cls._Interval._make(callargs[a] for a in cls._Interval._fields)
        return result


In [31]: index = SiDatetimeIndex(start='2018-01-01',
...:                              end='2018-01-04',
...:                              freq='1D',
...:                              closed='left')

In [38]: index.interval
Out[38]: Interval(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-04', freq='1D', closed='left')
```

Don't expect though that all the `pandas` methods (including the inherited ones in your class) will now magically start creating your overridden class. 
For that, you'll need to replace live references to the base class in loaded `pandas` modules that those methods use.
Alternatively, you can replace just the original's `__new__` -- then no need to replace references.

Comment: Thank you for a great explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Can something like this work for you?

```
index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2018-01-01', end='2018-01-04',  freq='1D', closed='left')

def get_end(index, freq):
    if freq == '1D':
        return(index.max()+1)

get_end(index, '1D')
```

You can write a logic for 1D/2D/1M. Also, make the column name of the dateIndex with Freq parameter as suffix/prefix 'purchase_date_1D' and parse it if you don't even want to give it as separate input.

Comment: No, the `freq` is not known in advance.